# Correlation analyses using robustfit in Matlab - interpreting p-values

Tags: matlab, math, regression, correlation, robust

I am using the `[b,stats] = robustfit(X,y)` to do a regression analysis of my data. Here is what I am doing:

```
[b,stats_visuomotor_visual] = robustfit(metaRatios(:,3), metaRatios(:,4))
```

As an output, I get:

```
b =

    0.5221
    0.2510

stats_visuomotor_visual = 

struct with fields:

    ols_s: 0.6643
 robust_s: 0.4185
    mad_s: 0.4337
        s: 0.4577
    resid: [27×1 double]
    rstud: [27×1 double]
       se: [2×1 double]
     covb: [2×2 double]
coeffcorr: [2×2 double]
        t: [2×1 double]
        p: [2×1 double]
        w: [27×1 double]
       Qy: [2×1 double]
        R: [2×2 double]
      dfe: 25
        h: [27×1 double]
     Rtol: 3.2366e-14
```

In p, there are two values:

```
0.0124044825989566
0.190293700095903
```

Why are there two values and what does each of them mean? I expected there to be one p-value.

Does anyone of you have expertise in this? I already looked through the documentation and forums. Some people were asking this question but they did not get any reply as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Best,
Caroline

Comment: Hi Caroline, it would be useful if you provide some input of your work around or some examples of your current results or what you're expecting. Specially, in scientific computing or maths.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Federico. I updated my question and I hope it is clearer now!